Can you still have an All Souls Day-ish Mass after 4:00 PM when it falls on a Saturday?
We started a "new tradition" a few years ago of having a Mass at the cemetery with a procession at night on All Souls Day.  This year, All Souls Day is on a Saturday.  According to this it means that the Mass is not truly an All Souls Day Mass. I'd imagine that also means that the vestments should be green and the readings from the Sunday Mass, etc... Does it also mean that the intentions ought to be regular Sunday intentions as opposed to something special that we'd be likely to do on All Souls Day? Is it inappropriate to treat the events after Mass as if it were still All Souls Day?

I don't believe you can, no, but you should ask the bishop to make sure. There may be some sort of dispensation he can give to your parish.

As far as the procession is concerned, however, I don't think it would be a problem when it comes to obtaining the indulgence, since the procession is still happening on the same calendar day.

Any Mass on Saturday may be an All Souls Day Mass.

@eques that's my question.  If it's an All Souls Day Mass AND it is after four PM, does it fulfill the Sunday obligation novus ordo perspective.  I've got no problem going to Mass three days in a row, but I'm not going to lie to my kids if they ask which Mass is obligatory.

@PeterTurner I would say the claim "and is not a Mass for All Souls’ Day." is not correct (from the link)

@eques if they read the 31st Sunday readings and wear green, then I wouldn't think it was an "All Souls Day Mass".

@PeterTurner It wouldn't be, but that's not what I meant. I meant that the claim a Saturday evening Mass cannot be a Mass for All Souls is incorrect. That is, nothing in Canon Law stipulates that the ability (Note: not obligation) to anticipate a Mass requires that the other liturgical day cease. I have answered to that effect somewhere around here in regards Christmas being adjacent to Sunday.

@eques yep, that's what happened, it was definitely an All Souls Day Mass at night.  Black vestments and three readings.  But no Creed.

That's also what I had locally.

Can you still have an All Souls Day-ish Mass after 4:00 PM when it falls on a Saturday?
As far as the mass itself is concerned, a mass after 4:00 PM, is to be celebrated as a Sunday mass. It is called a vigil or anticipated mass in the Ordinary Form of the Mass.
Thanks to Pope pius XII, we can celebrate a Sunday’s mass Saturday evening, but not before 4:00 PM.

VI. Si rerum adiuncta id necessario postulant, locorum Ordinariis concedimus ut Missae celebrationem vespertinis, ut diximus, horis permittere queant, ita tamen ut haec initium non habeat ante horam iv post meridiem, sive in festis de prae- cepto, quae adhuc vigent, sive in illis quae olim viguerunt, sive primis uniuscuiusque mensis feriis sextis, sive denique in illis sollemnibus, quae cum magno populi concursu celebren- tur, atque etiam, praeter hos dies, semel in hebdomada, ser- vato a sacerdote ieiunio trium horarum quoad cibum solidum et potus alcohólicos, unius autem horae quoad ceteros potus non alcohólicos. - 16 Januarii 1958 (page 23)

Although the mass propers would be of the Sunday’s mass, the celebrant could in part preach about the the Feast of All Souls as there is still a plenary indulgence that can be gained on this day and for the next eight (8) days for a soul in purgatory, when the usual conditions have been met.
At the conclusion of the Sunday’s anticipated mass, with all it’s rubrics concluded with, the priest and faithful would be free to take part in any pious activities directly related to the Feast of All Saints and it’s octave of plenary indulgences. After all, your Sunday obligation is now fulfilled.
Here is an example of what I am getting at:

So, for a Saturday evening Mass, the consideration of rankings is superseded by the fact that Sunday is a day of obligation [de precepto], while the Commemoration of All the Faithful Departed on Saturday is not. Therefore, the Mass formulary and Lectionary readings of the 31st Sunday in Ordinary Time took precedence on the evening of Saturday, November 2, 2019. - When a Feast or Solemnity falls on Saturday, which Mass and which Vespers are observed on that evening: that of the Feast or Solemnity, or that of Sunday?


For clarification, the plenary indulgence can be obtained 8 times, once per day. I'd like to encourage my Catholic brothers and sisters on this site to pray for the souls in purgatory and try to obtain these indulgences for them.

The ability to anticipate does NOT mean the regular liturgical day ceases. In fact, the canonical default would be the opposite. Anticipation is effectively an extension of the ability to fulfill an obligation, which does not curtail other obligations/abilities.

This answer's initial assertion cannot be right. The allowing of an anticipated Mass doesn't make it compulsory to anticipate the Sunday. A Mass of the Day is still possible, but attendance won't satisfy the Sunday obligation because it's not a Sunday Mass. The assertion of adoremus.org is therefore wrong as well: a Saturday evening Mass does not have to be a Mass of the Sunday.

@AndrewLeach the argument of Adoremus is based upon one comment from Rome, but the context of that comment seems lacking. It's definitely clear that Canon Law does not stipulate which Mass texts must be used to satisfy the obligation, so there's no question that a Mass of All Souls in the evening wouldn't fulfill obligation.

@eques There's no question? Really? If a Mass is on Saturday (not Sunday) and it's a Mass of the Saturday (not Sunday), surely it can't satisfy a Sunday obligation? Assisting at Mass after 4pm on Saturday could satisfy a Sunday obligation but only if the Sunday Mass has been anticipated as allowed by Pius XII.

@AndrewLeach There's no question because the canons pertaining to obligation make no requirement of the Mass text. Obligations in canon law must be interpreted broadly per canon law. https://www.canonlaw.info/2008/11/time-period-for-fulfilling-sunday.html

@eques There's "broadly" and "so broadly that the line you've drawn is over the horizon"

@AndrewLeach True, but your point would be? The point I was making is that obligations are interpreted broadly meaning that the time is understood with the larger extend (evening before through day of) but the particular Mass is not part of the obligation -- for one, its not mentioned in the Canons pertaining to the obligation (1246-1248).
